# Force MacPorts to build from source

Tags: macports

I want to build `coreutils` from source (because I’m testing a possible bug in the binary package). I tried

```
sudo port -s install coreutils
```

But this forces all packages to build from source. Is it possible to use binary packages for its dependencies, only build `coreutils` from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a solution, but I [got this answer from IRC](https://echelog.com/logs/browse/macports/1581202800):

```bsh
sudo port destroot coreutils
```

After that, the binary is found in folder `/opt/local/var/macports/build/` (because this is before the installation phase). This is good enough for me.